# custom login in Magento different page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am created custom login page. But i used same default login in different page. if i enter wrong password it redirect to default login. How i fix that? or please suggest me how to create custom login

Answer (score 5):

1. The controller which we want to override is:

   app/code/core/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
2. Our new module name is "Newcustom_Customer" where "Newcustom" is the namespace name and "Customer" is our module name.
3. Next we create an xml file called "Newcustom_Customer.xml" inside app/etc/modules/Newcustom_Customer.xml
4. So, we create a folder structure like this :: app/code/local/Newcustom/Customer and inside it, we create 2 more folders namely "etc" and "controllers".
5. Inside the app/code/local/Newcustom/Customer/etc folder, we create the configuration file for the module called config.xml
6. Inside the app/code/local/Newcustom/Customer/controllers folder, we copy paste the original app/code/core/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.

So, we need to work on mainly 3 files ::

a. app/etc/modules/Newcustom_Customer.xml
b. app/code/local/Newcustom/Customer/etc/config.xml
c. app/code/local/Newcustom/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

1. Let's start with the first file Newcustom_Customer.xml. It's content should be like this ::

   true
       local

The above piece of XML tells Magento that this module would run from "app/code/local" codepool.

2. Next check out the config.xml file for our module.

   0.1.0

   standard
        
          
            Newcustom_Customer

This XML would help to override the core Mage_Customer's controller.

3. And finally, the controller file itself (AccountController.php) needs to be modified. But it should extend the Mage_Customer's AccountController.php file's Mage_Customer_AccountController class.

Now, we are done. As we have extended the original 'Mage_Customer_AccountController' class, all the original functions are automatically available to this new over-ridden controller. And we can still add some more functionality by adding our custom functions to our class.  Some points need to be noted here :

1. Check how our extended class is defined with a name "Newcustom_Customer_AccountController".
2. We are extending the original Mage_Customer's controller class 'Mage_Customer_AccountController' to get the original functionality.

Comment: follow this link for better understanding http://chandanpatra.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-override-customer-account.html

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using Magento's default login post action (`Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginPost()`) to validate your form details. This method will call a protected method `_loginPostRedirect()` if some validation error happened. This function is actually responsible for redirecting to the default login page in this case.

You have two options here.

1. Rewrite the controller `Mage_Customer_AccountController` with a custom controller and modify the method `_loginPostRedirect()` according to your need.
2. Create a new controller to validate your custom login page. You can extend the default customer account controller class and thus inherit some common utilities from that class. ie your controller class should define like

   ```
   class Namespace_Module_Customer_AccountController 
       extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
   {

      public function postAction() {}
   }
   ```

Also in order to use your custom controller you need to modify the form action. For this you need to use a layout update.

File : `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <{your_custom_loginpage_handle}>
        <reference name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>custom/customer/login.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </{your_custom_loginpage_handle}>
</layout>
```

This will set a custom login template `custom/customer/login.phtml` for your custom login page form. All you need to do is copy paste the content of `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template/customer/form/login.phtml`  to `app\design\frontend\{package}\{theme}\template/custom/customer/login.phtml` and then edit the form action which should point to your custom controller.

```
 <form action="custom/customer_account/post" method="post" id="login-form" class="scaffold-form">
```